# Does PostGIS Catch Self-Intersections Involving the Start / End points to a Line or Area?

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to see if I can catch among other things a self-intersection which involves a start / end point of a geometry feature self-intersecting some other part of the same feature.  Obviously the start and end points of a proper feature will be the same.

I ask because I've heard some tools ignore start and end points altogether when trying to determine a self-intersection.  This can be a problem if either start or end points legitimately intersect some other point / line segment.

Would catching this specific kind of self-intersection be easily caught via ST_IsValid?

Answer (score 2):

You can test it yourself.

[image]

Draw a polygon that starts from the red dot and touches the same point

A WKT of one such polygon is

```
POLYGON ((
        320 620, 
        460 620, 
        460 500, 
        320 620, 
        320 500, 
        180 500, 
        180 620, 
        320 620
    ))
```

Ask a question from PostGIS

```
select ST_IsValid(
ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON (( 320 620, 460 620, 460 500, 320 620, 320 500, 180 500, 180 620, 320 620 ))'
    ));
```

The answer is "f".

```
select ST_IsSimple(
 ST_GeomFromText(
 'POLYGON (( 320 620, 460 620, 460 500, 320 620, 320 500, 180 500, 180 620, 320 620 ))'
     ));
```

The answer is "t".

```
select ST_IsValidReason(
 ST_GeomFromText(
 'POLYGON (( 320 620, 460 620, 460 500, 320 620, 320 500, 180 500, 180 620, 320 620 ))'
     ));
```

The answer is "Ring Self-intersection[320 620]".

How about the polygon ring as LineString?

```
select ST_IsValid(
ST_GeomFromText(
'LINESTRING ( 320 620, 460 620, 460 500, 320 620, 320 500, 180 500, 180 620, 320 620 )'
    ));
```

The answer is "t".

```
select ST_IsSimple(
ST_GeomFromText(
'LINESTRING ( 320 620, 460 620, 460 500, 320 620, 320 500, 180 500, 180 620, 320 620 )'
    ));
```

The answer is "f".

The answer to your question seems to be that PostGIS does catch self-intersections involving the start / end points to a line or area. You must use ST_IsValid for polygons and ST_IsSimple for linestrings. What I do not understand is why IsSimple returns "true" for the polygon. I thought it should be false. The documentation at http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsSimple.html says:

> ST_IsSimple — Returns (TRUE) if this Geometry has no anomalous
>   geometric points, such as self intersection or self tangency.

Comment: I don't actually have the tools to draw geometries to test things.  I only have the tools to inspect the data I have and in this case wasn't sure if there was even something that would come up positive.  I had the same thoughts about IsSimple.  Your example with using ST_IsValidReason pretty much sums up my concern and how to catch what I described.  I'm new to GIS and I wasn't for sure if "Ring Self-Intersection" was what you illustrated.  Many thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: You can just take a piece of paper and write the coordinates by hand if you do not want to download OpenJUMP and use its excellent WKT viewer/editor.

Comment: I have no latitude in downloading and installing software at work.  I could do so at home but wouldn't have access to the data I wanted to test... but many thanks for bringing up OpenJUMP.  This will be something I can do at home if I need to figure out what a postgis query would / should result in.